# Magento 2: Product URL Suffix problem with search (2.3.1)

Tags: magento2, url, search, suffix

We removed the values for url suffix from the configuration (removed .html). After rebuilding cache and reindexing from CLI the store works correct but the search function for some reason doesn't. The search results still go to .html urls and therefore get an 404 page. Also tried to remove all static content and rebuild but that doesn't work.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I again did reindexing through CLI and re-saved the config. Now is does work.